# My left join query does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to list PID, ProdName, Price, CateType, and the current balance of inventory quantity for each product in the store. To do this I need to subtract Qty from the SUM'ed Qty of another table in a Microsoft Access file.

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT pi.PID, ProdName, Price, CateType, pi.Qty - SUM(ol.Qty) AS [Qty Balance]
From Product_Info pi Left Join OrderLine ol
ON pi.PID = ol.PID;
```

When I attempt to run this code it comes up with an error code that says
"Your query does not include the specified expression 'PID' as part of an aggregate function"

I have read that I would need to use a group by to fix this however if I use a group by it just goes down the list of the values in my select statement and does not fix anything.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me fix this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an aggregation query but no `group by`.  Without sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the query, the only solution to suggest is to put the unaggregated columns in a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT pi.PID, ProdName, Price, CateType, pi.Qty - SUM(ol.Qty) AS [Qty Balance]
FROM Product_Info pi Left Join
     OrderLine ol
     ON pi.PID = ol.PID
GROUP BY pi.PID, ProdName, Price, CateType, pi.Qty;
```

Comment: OMG, you are a lifesaver! I don't know what I was doing wrong and I swear I used the same exact code you gave me and it didn't work. However, when I copied and pasted your code it worked! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

What you read is correct, a GROUP BY is needed with an aggregate function. It doesn't seem that a basic aggregate function is what you want, though Your statement *"if I use a group by it just goes down the list of the values in my select statement and does not fix anything"* shows why this is so. The error messages are telling you that anything besides the aggregated field that is in the `SELECT` list needs to be in the GROUP BY. But what you're seeing is that when you `GROUP BY` all the other relevant fields, each group is just one record (row). So the result set looks just like what you started with, since each record is its own group.

Depending on your version of Access, you may or may not be able to use `(pi.Qty - SUM(ol.QTY) OVER ()) AS [Qty Balance]`, but a better solution for your case would be to use `PARTITION BY`. If you want to find the balance for each product, and if PID is also a field in the Order Line table, you could use `(pi.Qty - (SELECT SUM(ol.QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY PID))) AS [Qty Balance]`.